# Azure SDK for Java - How to ignore SSL errors

Tags: java, azure, ssl

I have been trying to use the Azure SDK to fetch some information from an Azure account I have.

I need to disable ssl certificate checking.

```java
 public static final TrustManager[] UNQUESTIONING_TRUST_MANAGER = new TrustManager[]{
            new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new X509Certificate[0];
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
            }
    };

private SSLSocketFactory sslFactory() {
    try {
        final SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, UNQUESTIONING_TRUST_MANAGER, null);
        return sc.getSocketFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

 AzureTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(
     "XXX",
     "XXX",
     "XXX",
     AzureEnvironment.AZURE
 ).withSslSocketFactory(sslFactory());

Azure azure = Azure.configure().authenticate(credentials).withSubscription("XXX");
azure.resourceGroups().list()
```

Even with that SSLSocketFactory  I get:

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621)
```

I debugged sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.class:1008:
`((X509ExtendedTrustManager)var6).checkServerTrusted((X509Certificate[])var2.clone(), var4, this.conn);`

It passes twice in this line. The first time, var6 has my ssl factory, the second time, it's a different factory that throw that exception.

How can I disable the SSL checking?

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. Why do you need to disable certificate verification?

Comment: @second Sorry, I forgot. I just edited.

Comment: I believe I got NPE somewhere and did that. Let me try with null. Edit: same problem as before.

Comment: Yes, the PKIX error. There is a part in the sdk code that calls OkHttpClient >  X509TrustManager trustManager = Util.platformTrustManager();, which in turn calls TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()); (PKIX) - I am looking for a way to make the samething I did for SSL to PKIX. If that makes sense.

Comment: Anyway it might be easier to supply the correct ca-certificates instead.